# pipe data during execution

Tags: linux, bash, perl

I would like to modify the output of a program in realtime without waiting its execution end.

For instance I have this program: **speak.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl 
use 5.010;
use Time::HiRes qw( usleep );
for(1..10) {
    say "I am counting: $_";
    usleep(100000);
}
```

And this one: **wrapper.pl**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl     
print "You are saying: $_\n" while(<>);
```

At the execution of this command:

```
./speak.pl | ./wrapper.pl
```

Unfortunately nothing happens until **speak.pl** terminates its execution. Is there a way to modify the output data of **speak.pl** during its execution ?

I also tried pass by an intermediate file:

```
./speak.pl > tmp & ./read.pl tmp
```

With this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl 
use 5.010;
use File::Tail;
my $file=File::Tail->new(name=>$ARGV[0], maxinterval=>300, adjustafter=>7);
while (defined(my $line=$file->read)) {
  print "You're saying: $line";
}
```

But again it seems the output file is written only at the end of execution.

Any clues ?

P.S. I am running on Cygwin I hope it doesn't make any differences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is likely related to buffering. Data are stored up to a certain size before being sent through the pipe (or flushed at the end of the execution).

Try using usig `stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 ./speak.pl | stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 ./wrapper.pl` to disable buffering.

As you use perl, please consider [this link](http://perl.plover.com/FAQs/Buffering.html) to disable perl's own buffering mechanism.